# Function declaration in variable object

Tags: javascript

```
test(); //working

function test(){//do something}
```

Is this related to (global)variable object? Does the function push to variable object before execution process start?

UPDATE:
Ok my real question is how "hoist" work. To understand you need to take a look at [execution context of javascript](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/),and yes it related to variable object(which is part of execution context).

Comment: This works due to [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

Comment: @enix:please accept the answer if you think its worthy!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Scope Cheatsheet on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)

`function foo() { }` [hoists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting) `foo` to the top of scope automatically

> Is this related to (global)variable object? Does the function push to variable object before execution process start?

Nope, it's just hoisting.

---

Consider this example:

```
foo();
// ReferenceError: foo is not defined

(function(){
  foo();
  function foo (){
    console.log("A");
  };
})();
// A

(function(){
  foo();
  function foo (){
    console.log("B");
  };
})();
// B

foo();
// ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Hoisting just "lifts" the variable name to the top of the scope.

---

**My opinion:**

I **never** write functions as:

```
function foo() { ... }
```

I prefer being explicit because magic behavior sucks; I **always** write functions as

```
var foo = function() { ... }
```

If I feel like the function needs a name, I will give it a name, but still define with `var`

```
var foo = function foo() { ... }
```

---

[@bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825789/bfavaretto) raises a valid concern:

> About your opinion... var foo = function() { ... } also hoists foo to the top, but with an undefined value. So there's implicit stuff going on there too

True, it does hoist `foo` with an `undefined` value, but things will all work as desired.

```
foo();
// TypeError: undefined is not a function
// This is good. We don't want the above function to run like that.
// This is a fatal error; the script won't even continue to run as-is.
// Comment out the above line to get it to run.

var foo = function foo() {
  console.log("foo");
};

var foo2 = function foo() {
  console.log("foo2");
};

// Even with the same function name, these two functions will
// output the correct values.
foo();  // foo
foo2(); // foo2
```

All of that said, it would be silly to have two functions with the same name identifier in the same scope. But, even if you *do* make a mistake and write bad code like that, if you're using function expressions as described above, the code would still work anyway. If you just used named functions like in the original question, it certainly will not.

Comment: The behavior isn't magic and is same in most mainstream languages.

Comment: By "magic" I simply mean "implicit"; implicit things are not always straightforward and they are the cause of lots of coding wtfs.

Comment: About your opinion... `var foo = function() { ... }` also hoists `foo` to the top, but with an undefined value. So there's implicit stuff going on there too.

Comment: @bfavaretto, you're correct, but there is no undesired behavior happening. I made an edit to my post.

Comment: @naomik Point taken. And great answer!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about **Hoisting** here.
I always prefer labeled function instead of function expression.

***this is a function expression:***

```
//Declaration 1
var foo = function(){

// code goes here
}
```

- The func expression in this case is anonymous but assigned to a var foo.
  for reference

***This is a labeled function :***

```
//Declaration 2
function foo(){
 // same code here
 }
```

- There's not really any great reason to do expression to var. You
  should always try to use labeled statements for constructors,so you
  can identify an object's 'type' via its constructor.
- people mostly use this where **hoisting** is needed.**Hoisting simply means
  calling something before it is defined**.

  ***Very very simple example***:

  ```
  foo(); // alerts 'hello'
  function foo() {alert('hello');}
  V/s 
  foo(); // throws an error since foo is undefined
  var foo = function() {alert('hello');}
  ```

REFER:[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Where you say "labeled function" I think you mean "named function".

Comment: Actually, they're called "function *declarations*"

Comment: diff people will call it differently,but the point is understanding the logic behind.